# Win32 Project Generating MFC error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I am working on a Win32 project in Visual Studio 2010. it is generating an MFC error, the error is given below

> error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
>
> IntelliSense: #error directive: WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include

My Question is why WIN32 project is generating MFC error, and how should i remove this error, kindly guide me

Comment: One the general property page for the project make sure in the "Use of MFC" field it says "Use Standard Windows Libraries".  Otherwise, show the headers you're including.

Comment: I have already done that .. but my problem still persist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try this:

Change

> Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library

As

> Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that one of the headers you're including is including 'afx.h'. The first thing that header does is check to see if _DLL as been defined and if that's present it looks for _AFXDLL and shows this error message if it's not been defined. Here's the relevant bit from afx.h

```
#ifdef _DLL
#ifndef _AFXDLL
#error Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
#endif
#endif
```

If you don't want to include MFC go to your project properties and under **C/C++ -> Advanced** switch **Show Includes** ON to see where afx.h is being included.

Comment: Yes, until you figure out what is including afx.h you'll get that error. Have you tried looking through the Show Includes list?

Comment: afxwin.h was included, i have excluded it, the 2nd error has been removed but the first one is still there

Comment: Use the same technique to fix that. Use a program like Agent Ransack to look through the MFC source and you'll see that the error is generated by including afxv_w32.h.